# Cannot display EJS page in node.js web app

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I have a simple nodejs application with folder structure like this (not a full structure, but enough for this question).

```
index.js
views
- index.ejs
- about.ejs
```

In `index.js`, I have

```
app.use("/", (request, response) => {
  response.render('index')
})
app.use("/about", (request, response) => {
  response.render('about') 
})
// Also tried with extension (index.ejs and about.ejs)
```

In `index.ejs`, I have

```
<a href = "../about"> About </a>
```

**The problem**

1. When I go to root url (`localhost:port/`), index.ejs is displayed.
2. In index.ejs, I click on the link `About`, the url is changed to (`localhost:port/about`), but `about.ejs` is not rendered. However, checking F12 sources in browser (Microsoft Edge Chrominum), `about.ejs` is in there.
3. When I go to the link directly by typing the url to url bar, `index.js` is displayed. The behavior (in F12/sources) is the same compared step 2.
4. When I comment out (`app.use("/")` block in `index.js`, about.ejs is accessible and displayed on screen.
5. **Note**, the navigation works perfectly if they are html pages and served by node.js server. Everything has been test only on local server.

**Question**
What is the cause of this and how to fix?

**Why do I use EJS?**
I want to create a dynamic front end based on DB query.

---

There seems to be multiple questions about this on Stackoverflow, I have tried multiple of them and none fix my issue, or clearly explain the cause.

Comment: `use` is for middleware. You should be using `get` for GET request endpoints.

Comment: Thank you, It does solve the issue. Although I'm new to web development, my bad for making this simple mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Quentin answered, the issue is due to my use of `use`. For the request, which is `GET` in this case, I have to use `get` function, and it fixes the problem.
`use` is applicable when I want to decompose my index.js or use middleware.